# Laravel Mix relative path issue

Tags: css, webpack, minify, laravel-5.6, laravel-mix

I'm trying to conacatenate plain css files. Here is the `webpack.min.js` script:

```
mix.styles([
    'public/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
    'public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'public/assets/layouts/layout3/css/themes/default.min.css',
    'public/assets/layouts/layout3/css/custom.min.css',
], 'public/css/global.css');
```

In the resulting `global.css` file the url to the Font Awesome fonts directory points to the wrong address.
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0`

**How can I process these relative urls?**

I need the above url point to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0` in the `global.css` file.
This is just an example there are other image files which have the wrong url.

I've tried [processCssUrls](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#url-processing) option.